# Good resource for ASP.Net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Can anybody tell me about any good resource(Link, blog, book(would be best)) for MVC **3**.

I have already visited asp.net MVC tutorials and videos and many other blogs and have taken the basic knowledge of it, now I want some good and higher level knowledge.

Almost every tutorial of MVC 3 on the net gives only "My First MVC 3 Application" kind of knowledge, I want something beyond that now.

Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good resource books/sites for learning MVC3 in detail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899384/good-resource-books-sites-for-learning-mvc3-in-detail)

Comment: Actually that thread was not shown when I was putting the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework 3rd Edition, this Book dive deep on various aspects and customization of the framework.

http://www.apress.com/9781430234043

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at the best MVC 3 resource on the web. Nothing beats StackOverflow.

However, I would recommend TekPub's 'Real World ASP.NET MVC3' series. Rob Conery is great.